# US tourist visa

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

I came to the US in 2013 on a student visa. I was working from 2015 to June 2018 on Optional Practical Training (OPT). I never get picked on my H1B application.

Current situation:

I got a Canadian work permit and I am moving to Canada to join the work. I am in India right now and want to get a US tourist visa now so that I can visit my girlfriend. I am going for an interview tomorrow, can my previous history with the US affect my chances of getting a tourist visa? What can they ask me?

Comment: Did you overstay in the USA? I mean did you fall out of status?

Comment: I don't see what we can tell you that will help. Whatever we say isn't going to affect the actuality or outcome of your interview.

Comment: Not off-topic; asking about a tourist visa.  But it is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4):

The immigration office may ask if you’ve ever overstayed a visa. Given that OPT status is usually only given for 12 months (extensions are possible for some students upon application) and you state you’ve been on OPT for three years, you may need to prove that you did not overstay by showing that you’ve been in status the entire time.

They may also be concerned that if your OPT status has ended and you don’t have a job  to go back to, you may be trying to illegally work. So you want to bring proof of employment.